# Selenium Find Only the "Deepest" Elements Containing a Specific String

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to retrieve a list of elements from a webpage that contain a specific string. I'm evaluating the XPath using a selenium `ISearchContext.FindElement(By.XPath(...))`, so the XPath engine is the one supported by the browser.

Below is a minimal sample page created by me, but in a real world scenario I cannot modify the page's structure:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Nav Item 1</li>
        <li>Nav Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab deserunt dolore eius est
            facere incidunt magni
            minus molestiae natus, nesciunt nostrum, officia perspiciatis placeat provident reiciendis saepe sed, sit
            voluptates.</p>
        <p class="price">1.150<span class="comma">,</span><sup>00</sup> <span class="currency">EUR</span></p>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <p class="price">1.150<span class="comma">,</span><sup>00</sup> <span class="currency">EUR</span></p>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        1<span>.</span>150<span class="comma">,</span><sup>00</sup> <span class="currency">EUR</span>
    </footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The elements I'm looking for are `[p.price, p.price, footer]`; basically **only** the "deepest" elements containing the string `1.150,00 EUR`.

If I evaluate the following XPath in Chrome's Developer Tools Console

```js
$x("//*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')][contains(ancestor::*, '1.150,00 EUR')][not(contains(child::*, '1.150,00 EUR'))]")
```

the result I get is `[body, div.content, p.price, p.price, footer]`.

I'm looking for a solution that still lets me remain in the Selenium context so I can further access element properties (such as element position). It doesn't necessarily have to involve XPath and I am also open to using another browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
//*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')]
   [not(
      *[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')]
   )]
```

= "all elements whose text value contains '1.150,00 EUR' and don't have a child element whose text value contains '1.150,00 EUR'"

Comment: Thank you, that gives me the expected result. Could you please explain what the difference is between your approach and `//*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')][not(contains(*, '1.150,00 EUR'))]` which results in `[html, body, div.content, p.price, p.price, footer]`?

Comment: The XPath you ask about (`//*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')][not(contains(*, '1.150,00 EUR'))]`) produces an error when I try it. It doesn't produce the result you mention (`html, body, div.content, p.price, p.price, footer`)

Comment: The first part of that XPath `//*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')]` generates a set of elements whose text value contains ` '1.150,00 EUR'``, but the predicate `[not(contains(*, '1.150,00 EUR'))]` fails because it attempts to pass `*` as the first parameter of the `contains` function. The first parameter to the `contains` function should be a string, or something that can be converted to a string automatically, but the expression `*` in fact yields a set of child elements, which may have more than one member, in which case it can't be converted to a string automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Given that HTML tree, this xpath selects the requested elements

```
$x("//*[.='EUR']/parent::*[contains(., '1.150,00 EUR')]")
```

Result

```
Array(3) [ p.price, p.price, footer ]
```